# loop through range object excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Using interop for c# I have a range object as follows:

```
Range rangeAToV = ws.get_Range("A1", "V1");
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
foreach (var cell in rangeAToV.Cells)
  {

  }
```

is this wrong? I'm trying to set `cell.value2` but that's now showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collection object to iterate through is the `Range` itself, not the `Cells` property:

```
foreach (Range cell in rangeAToV)
{
    // Do stuff with cell.
}
```

Comment: even with this though, I'm only getting 4 method call options on cell; "ToString, GetHashCode, Equals, and GetType"

Comment: @AbdulAhmad - Probably because C# can't coerse/determine type. If you just explicitly declare `cell` as a `Range` instead of using `var` it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that isn't giving me an issue: change `"var cell"` in the loop to:

```
foreach (Range cell in rangeAToV) {
 //stuff
}
```